# Invoking delete on an octree array

Tags: c++, destructor, octree

So I wrote an octree struct, as follows:

```
struct octree{
    static const int maxdepth=8;
    octree* child[8];
    uint32_t rgb;//candidates for the extra 8 bits: alpha, lighting, shape(to reduce size)
    uint8_t shape;
    ~octree(){delete[] child;}
};
```

The concern that I have is with the destructor...
Will it call the destructors of the children or do I have to do that myself?

Comment: fun fact: the site rejected this question with no hint as to why until  looked up "stackoverflow post does not meet our quality standards" and concluded that i should capitalize the starts of sentences and i...

Comment: Also, the title doesn't describe the problem very well. What is "octree"? I didn't know until I actually looked at the question.

Comment: Octree is a pretty well-known term. I mean, it has a tag. Unless the title has changed since your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have declared is an array of 8 `octree*` values.  You cannot delete the array itself.

You should instead do this:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    if( child[i] ) delete child[i];
```

If you want to delete them all in one hit, you could define it like this:

```
octree * child;

//...
child = new octree [8];

//...
delete [] child;
```

The reason being that in an octree you either have no children or 8 children.

And yes: when you delete an `octree` instance, its destructor will be called.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is totally broken.  Calling `delete` on an array results in undefined behaviour.  You would need to delete each element individually (assuming it's appropriate to delete them).

A far better solution is to use a container class (e.g. `std::vector` or `std::array`), which automatically deals with cleanup for you.  If you're not prepared to use an existing solution, then you need to read about the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: using an already existing solution? where is the fun in that ;P

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not allocated dynamic memory for the `child` array, you should not use the `delete[]` operator to free it. However you can `delete` each individual element of that array to free each individual child `octree`. This will then call the destructors of each of the children.

A good rule to remember is that each `new` must have a matching `delete` (and vice versa). And each `new[]` must have a matching `delete[]` (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

As it is, the destructor will only delete the array, but not the child octree objects.  You must delete them explicitly (before deleting the array, of course).